# Ubuntu fails to boot when USB/external HDD plugged in

Tags: boot, grub2

**Issue**

If I leave a USB flash drive/external HDD plugged into my computer and boot/reboot it, it will not get past the initial BIOS splash screen.

**Troubleshooting Attempts**

Removing all such devices prior to boot/reboot removes the issue. This issue has persisted through at least two upgrades of Ubuntu, possibly three, and several complete reinstallations.

My boot order specifies that the computer's HDD is the priority:

[image: Boot order screenshot]

(Actually, there are two HDDs under that option - an SDD on which my OS is installed, and a separate HDD. Somehow it knows to boot from the SSD, but isn't able to figure out not to boot from random USB sticks when they are present)

This only seems to happen with drives that do not have an OS installed. If I plug in an Ubuntu LiveUSB, it boots to the OS normally (unless I choose to boot from the USB manually).

**Hardware Specs**

- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-X58A-UD3R
- OS: Ubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 0):

One the partitions on USB flash drive/external HDD has the "Boot" flag set. That tells the BIOS to try to read a bootable system from that partition. If there isn't one, it can't. Clear the "Boot" flag.

Read `man fdisk`.

Comment: I had to use `parted` rather than `fdisk` as both of the problem drives are GPT-partitioned; neither drive has the boot flag set.